# How can I improve the efficiency of Core-Plot

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

The Core-Plot freaked me out...
I got a navigationController, and push into a viewController that is initialized with hostingView (from core-plot. I draw some scatterPlot and barPlot on that..)  with animated:YES. But the transition animation is a little bit stuck, not smooth. How can I improve that? When coding with core-plot, is there something I've got to keep in mind?

And there's also another problem. I need to download data from server and refresh the plots once the viewWillAppear gets called.  So..where should I put the plots drawing function? If I put it in the viewWillAppear Method, all the views appeared at the same time, however, I want to display base view (like tabBarController's tabBar) first and then show the plots... For this, I put the plots drawing function in the viewDidAppear method.... Is it the right way to do that? Well, I got a bigger problem, that is, low memory alert! That problem didn't occur if
the drawing method is put in viewWillAppear function. I didn't get it... is there somebody could do me a favor? Thanks in advance!

By the way, I drew a lot of labels for the plots, is that the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Run the profiler **Instruments.app** to understand the problem and your program's execution better.

Answer (score 0):

One issue that I've noticed with Core Plot's scatterPlot is that it assumes un-ordered data… meaning that it iterates linearly thru the entire data set range checking each data point to see if it's in the desired range to display and then plotting each if so. A much faster implementation for sorted data would be to binary search for the (sub-)range of data points that intersect the desired range to display and then just iterate that (sub-)range of data points plotting them (without the overhead of testing each one as you go).